# How to generate dynamic file naming for flat file in ssis?

Tags: ssis

Hi I am trying to use the expression column in flat file connection manager to generate file with dynamic naming e.g

File-ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt

I understand that I can use getdatepart but what is the exact method call to get the hh, mm and ss? Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

[Pragmatic works SSIS Expression Cheat Sheet](http://pragmaticworks.com/LearningCenter/Resources/CheatSheets/SSISExpressionCheatSheet.aspx) is a good start.  You can expand to your situation by using `(DT_WSTR, 2) datepart("HH",getdate())`  to get the hour portion,  `(DT_WSTR, 2) datepart("n",getdate())` to get the minutes and   `(DT_WSTR, 2) datepart("s",getdate())` to get the seconds.  You will need to add logic  in to ensure that values less than 10 still get two digits (i.e. 01 05) etc.  For Day, month and Year, there are function DAY() MONTH() and YEAR() that shortcut the equivalent datepart() functions.